# Screen Orientation for Portrait and Landscape Orientation in iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation

I have a situation where I want to call separate method for different Orientation (Portrait and Landscape).

For example:

```
If (Orientation == Portrait)
{
  Some method a;
}

Elseif (Orientation == Landscape)
{
  Some method b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` to know the orientation.

then I use this method

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
//Do something if landscape
} else {
//Do something in portrait
}
```

don't use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` because it doesn't work properly if the device is on a table, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
         // code for landscape orientation      
    }

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
         // code for Portrait orientation       
    }
```

`UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape` and `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait` are the macro's.

Comment: This is not the best, as there are `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`

Answer (score 0):

```
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if(deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    ...
else  ...
```

the enum is `UIDeviceOrientation[something]`

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
            || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)

```
    {// perform ua operation for landscape mode
```

} else{

//perform ua operation for portrait  mode
};

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-c:**

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        printf("Portrait");
    } else {
        printf("Landscape");
    }
}
```